# How can I paint in an specific JPanel when more than one in same frame- Java

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, draw

Updated - this is related with the following link I posted yesterday.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15916360/swing-gui-application-in-java-with-multiple-frames

I apologize if I am doing something wrong here, I tried to write in my previous post and I couldn't find a way to do it beyond the comments box.

I did some changes on my code, now I am working with 3 JPanels. I created a class for each panel except the main one that will hold in a CardLayout the other two. The main panel is created in my main class and application at the same time.
Now I am trying to paint a happy face in one of the two panels when I press a button but it doesn't work.

```
import statements;


public class JDataAnalyzerGui extends JFrame {

private static final String INTRO = "welcome";   
private static final String OPERATIONS = "operations";   
private CardLayout cardlayout = new CardLayout();   
private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(cardlayout);   
private WelcomePanel welcomePanel = new WelcomePanel();   
private OperationPanel operationPanel = new OperationPanel();   
private ReadFiles aFileReader;

public JDataAnalyzerGui() {

// adding panels to the main panel

    mainPanel.add(welcomePanel.getMainComponent(), INTRO);     
    mainPanel.add(operationPanel.getMainComponent(), OPERATIONS);

    welcomePanel.addAcceptActionListener(new ActionListener() {    //moves to next view where the buttons are and were the drawing should happen

        @Override     
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {                
            int input = Integer.parseInt(welcomePanel.userInput.getText());  
            boolean isValid = isOptionValid(input);         
            if(isValid) {                
                cardlayout.show(mainPanel, OPERATIONS);              
                performActions(aFileReader);             
            }         
        }    
    });      

    operationPanel.addReturnActionListener(new ActionListener() {  //returns to welcome window         
        @Override        
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
            Graphics pen = getGraphics();
            Object source = e.getSource();           
            if(source == operationPanel.aButton8) {              
                operationPanel.results.setText(null);
                welcomePanel.userInput.setText(null);                
                cardlayout.show(mainPanel, INTRO);           
            }
```

// when button1 is pressed I want to draw a String on panel2 from operationPanel.

```
            else if(source == operationPanel.aButton1) {     

                operationPanel.results.setText("The maximun opening value was " + Calculations.hiOpenValue);  
                operationPanel.panel2.setBackground(Color.GREEN); 
                pen.setFont(new Font("Broadway", Font.ITALIC, 12));
                pen.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                pen.drawString("this is a test", 20, 40);

            }
            // code for the rest of buttons
        }      
    });   
}


private boolean isOptionValid(int option) {    

    switch(option) {    

    case 1:         
        aFileReader = new ReadFiles("newMSFT.csv");         
        return true;        

    case 4:             
        Object[] options = { "YES", "CANCEL" };         
        int reply = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Are you sure you want to go?", "Confirm Exit", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);         
        if(reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
        System.exit(0);         
        return false;       

    default:        
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "That is an invalid option. Please try again");     
        return false;   
    }   
}


public void performActions(ReadFiles obj) {     
    // code for numeric calculations
}   


private JComponent getMainComponent() {      
    return mainPanel;   
}

private static void createAndShowUI() {     

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Data Analyzer");      
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);      
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JDataAnalyzerGui().getMainComponent());     
    frame.pack();      
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);      
    frame.setVisible(true);  
}


public static void main(String[] args) {      
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {         
        public void run() {            
            createAndShowUI();         
        }      
    });   
}
}
```

------------------------------  Operation Jpanel
    import statements;

```
class OperationPanel {

JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();  
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());        
JPanel panel2 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
JPanel panel3 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
JLabel results = new JLabel ("");

JButton aButton1 = new JButton("Max Open");;   // 8 buttons in total, this is the one for painting

JButton aButton8 = new JButton("Return to Main");

public OperationPanel() {      

    mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));      
    mainPanel.add(panel1); 
    mainPanel.add(panel3);
    panel2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);      
    mainPanel.add(panel2);      
    panel1.add(aButton1);     
    // adding all buttons to panel1     
    panel2.add(results);                

}

public JComponent getMainComponent() {      
    return mainPanel;   
}

public void addReturnActionListener(ActionListener listener) {   // el que retorna a welcome view      
    aButton8.addActionListener(listener);     
    aButton1.addActionListener(listener);
    //addActionListener for all buttons
}
```

}

-------------------- Welcome panel
    class WelcomePanel {

```
private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();   
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();       
JPanel panel2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5,1));        
JPanel panel3 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    JLabel greetings = new JLabel("Welcome to Data Analizer"); 
Font bigFont = new Font("Comic Sans", Font.BOLD, 30);
JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Please select one of these options:");  
JLabel label2 = new JLabel("1. newMSFT.csv");
JLabel label3 = new JLabel("2. XXX.csv");
JLabel label4 = new JLabel("3. YYY.csv");
JLabel label5 = new JLabel("4. QUIT");      
Font bigFont2 = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20);   
JTextField userInput = new JTextField(10);  
JButton aButton = new JButton("Accept");

public WelcomePanel() {

    mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));      
    greetings.setFont(bigFont);      
    label1.setFont(bigFont2);
    label2.setFont(bigFont2);
    label3.setFont(bigFont2);
    label4.setFont(bigFont2);
    label5.setFont(bigFont2);      

    mainPanel.add(panel1);     
    mainPanel.add(panel2);     
    mainPanel.add(panel3);
    panel1.add(greetings);
    panel2.add(label1);
    panel2.add(label2);
    panel2.add(label3);
    panel2.add(label4);
    panel2.add(label5);      
    panel3.add(userInput);     
    panel3.add(aButton);

    }

public void addAcceptActionListener(ActionListener listener) {  // este es el que llama a segunda ventana o view      
    aButton.addActionListener(listener);      
    userInput.addActionListener(listener);   
}

public JComponent getMainComponent() {     
    return mainPanel;   
}
```

}

I can't figure out how to draw in an specific panel.

Thanks

Comment: `WelcomePanel` For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I'm sure you don't write code that is all left justified, so don't expect us to read code that is not reasonably formatted. Edit your question and fix the code.

Answer (score 3):

### You could...

Use the glass pane...

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class TestGlassPane04 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestGlassPane04();
    }

    public TestGlassPane04() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }
                
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2, 10, 10));
                frame.add(createBox(1));
                frame.add(createBox(2));
                frame.add(createBox(3));
                frame.add(createBox(4));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setGlassPane(new GlassPane());
                frame.getGlassPane().setVisible(true);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    
    protected JLabel createBox(int box) {
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Box " + box);
        label.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(new LineBorder(Color.GRAY), new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10)));
        return label;
    }
    
    public class GlassPane extends JPanel {
        
        private BufferedImage background;
        
        public GlassPane() {
            setOpaque(false);
            try {
                background = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/sillydash.png"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }
        
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            if (background != null) {
                int x = (getWidth() - background.getWidth()) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - background.getHeight()) / 2;
                g2d.drawImage(background, x, y, this);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }
    
}
```

Take a look at [How to use Root Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) for more details...

### Or you could...

Use a JXLayer/[JLayer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html) to accomplish a more localized version of a glass pane...