# Why there are too much layering in the Container in the swing?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, contentpane

Can anybody tell me what is the difference between the below Code

```
JFrame jf=new JFrame();
JButton jb=new JButton();
jf.add(jb);
```

and

```
JFrame jf=new JFrame();
Container c=jf.getContentPane();
JButton jb=new JButton();
c.add(jb);
```

Even I am not Clear about the RootPane,LayeredPane,GlassPane. What is the use of RootPane?? I have never used it in my coding. I have read it from the below link

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html

but not too much clear because there is no practical situation where I have used the above.
Thanks for your answer!!

Answer (score 1):

As of Java 5, there is no difference between you code examples.  `JFrame#add` is now redirected to `JFrame#getContentPane` on your behalf.

Before Java 5, it would throw an exception, which meant you had to add your components directly to the content pane yourself.

The `JRootPane` is used to provide a light weight container onto which other Swing components can be added.  More importantly, it provides a means by which the top level Swing containers can organise themselves.

The `JRootPane` is made of layers.  At the bottom is the `JMenuBar` and content pane and above that is the glass pane.

Because of the way it's constructed, the `JRootPane` can actually have a number of additional layers (typically between the content pane and the glass pane), this is typically used for things like popups.

The glass pane acts as a overlay which can be used to render content over the top of everything else (as well as block mouse and keyboard events).

Take a look at [How to use Root Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html).

Normally, other then the content pane and glass pane, you wouldn't typically use any of the other parts of the root pane.

You could also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961472/how-can-i-paint-in-an-specific-jpanel-when-more-than-one-in-same-frame-java/15961655#15961655) for a quick example of a glass pane in use

Answer (score 1):

Both are same...
Both are added in java.awt.Container object.

JFrame and Container have following hierarchy 
Case 1: JFrame#add()--> Frame#add()--> Window#add()--> Container#add() // Component add to container

Case 2: JFrame#getContentPane() --> getRootPane().getContentPane(); it will return Container object(Container#add)

Comment: Case 1 is (partially) wrong.  As of Java 5, `addImpl` delegates to the content pane.  Before, it throw an exception