# Swing: how to paint an animation over every component, JPanel, JButton, etc?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, awt

I'm trying to paint over every component in my Swing application.

what I have:

```
jButton b = new JButton();
b.addActionListener(e -> fillEntireScreen())
f.add(b);
f.setVisible()...f.setSize()...f.setDefaultCloseOperation()...
```

where `fillEntireScreen()` simply is an animation that expands over the screen. I override `Component's` `paintComponent()`, painting over the frame, not a panel or anything. 
`fileEntireScreen()` works without the button, but does not work when I add the button, as the animation is behind the button.

how can I paint  *over the button?* 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `glassPane` instead - See [How to Use Root Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) for more details and [How can I paint in an specific JPanel when more than one in same frame- Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15961472/how-can-i-paint-in-an-specific-jpanel-when-more-than-one-in-same-frame-java/15961655#15961655) for an example.

Alternatively you could use a `JLayer`, but's more complicated and may not suit your needs.  See [How to Decorate Components with the JLayer Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html)